# How can you fix checkboxes and their labels in SimpleForms RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm using a SimpleForms and generating checkboxes for each record in a table.  The labels for the checkboxes are displayed, but the checkboxes are all generated in a large bunch to the right of all the labels.  Has anyone seen this behavior and know how to fix it?

Here is a screenshot.[image]

Here's the code I'm using to generate these checkboxes.

```
<%= f.association :counties, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => County.all.sort, :selected => @job.counties, :inline_label => true, :label => false %>
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Can you share your HTML output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but this should work

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :county_ids,County.all.sort,:id,:name,:selected => @job.counties do |county| %>
     <td><%= county.text %></td>
     <td><%= county.check_box %></td>
<% end %>
```

This will call :id and :name on `County` objects and return them to the block as `text = name` and `check_box = id`.

county_ids was just a guess at structure based on simple_form's example.

Or possibly

```
<%= f.association :counties,:selected => @job.counties do |county_form| %>
   <% County.all.sort.each do |county| %>
      <td><%= county.name %></td>
      <td><%= county_form.input :county, as: :boolean, label: false %></td>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

both `collection_check_boxes` and `association` take a block so that you can format them appropriately to your scenario. I think the main issue is that you are using a table structure and it is rendering all your check boxes in a single `<td>` element. `inline_label` seems like a mute option since you are not rendering a label anyway.

Comment: This worked.  It groups the checkbox and the label together.  Although it still requires a little formatting, which I can do.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: No problem. `simple_form_for` is one of my favorite gems but using it with tables can get cumbersome. If you don't mind me asking which method did you use? Also thanks for putting me over 1k rep.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`<%= f.input :parties, {:collection => County.all.sort, :as => :check_boxes, :checked => @job.counties, :inline_label => true, :label => false} %>`